# How to merge 3 cells with using an absolute cell reference in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to put together a VBA macro Im trying to reference Sheet1A8(CSWAH_) as an absolute cell reference and merge  SeparateA7(Last Name) and SeperateB7(First Name) so they'll display in SeperateE7(ASA Naming) and be able to carry it all the way down from E7 to E100.
Is something like this even possible?

[image: Excel VBA Macro]

Comment: Why not doing it via formula? `=$B$1&A7&","&B7` for E7 and then copy down should do the trick

Comment: That was what the line [  .Offset(0, 2) = "CSWAH_" & lastN & ", " & firstN  ] was supposed to do in my answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45929082/copy-over-column-data-and-adding-vba-right-function   You could substitute sepSh.Range($B$1) for "CSWAH_" in that line

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")      'change Sheet1 to your data sheet
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last row with data using Column A
        Set rng = .Range("E7:E" & lastRow)               'set range in Column E
        rng.Formula = "=$B$1&""_""&A7&"",""&B7"          'enter formula in range
        rng.Value = rng.Value                            'display values in range
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]